# How to implement a condition with two loops

Tags: java

```
public void PlayforMe()
{
    for (int i=game.size()-1;i>=1;i--)
    {
        Card a = game.get(i);
        Card b = game.get(i-1);
        if (a.getSuit().equals(b.getSuit()) | (a.getCardNum().equals(b.getCardNum())))
        {
            game.remove(b);
            break;
        }
    }

    for (int j=game.size()-1;j>=3;j--)
    {
        Card c = game.get(j);
        Card d = game.get(j-3);
        if (c.getSuit().equals(d.getSuit()) | (c.getCardNum().equals(d.getCardNum())))
        {
            game.set(j-3,game.get(j));
            game.remove(j);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I have written this piece of Java code for a solitaire type game I'm making in Java code. I'm very new to the language (and programming in general). I have an arrayList for my deck and an arrayList for my 'game'. In this method/move I have it so it will find the card nearest the end of the dealt cards and 'swap' it with the card directly before it if the suit or the card number are the same.

If this move isn't an option with the cards dealt then I need it to go through the second loop which finds the card nearest the end of the dealt cards and 'swaps' it with the card [3] places before it if the suit or the card number are the same.

They work individually, but I can't get a condition working (e.g. I've tried the if statement) that will go through the first loop, and if it doesn't successfully remove a card it will go through the second loop.

The method should only preform one move, prioritising moving a card onto the card next(before) it if the conditions are met. I can make it so it'll go through both loops (i.e. putting the piece of code into two methods and calling them both from my menu) but I need it to do the first loop and only do the second if the first one turns out unsuccessful (i.e. card b isn't removed/game.remove(b); isn't called.)

If anyone has any suggestions I'd appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to put `Boolean finished = false;`  at the start of the function, then `finished = true` when you have finished. Then put `if (finished) { ... }` round your second loop.

Alternatively put a `return` in the first loop when finished. This will return out your function and execute no more lines of code. Although some people consider this bad style.

Answer (score 0):

If the first `for` loop succeeds, `return` instead of `break`ing.

Comment: Watch out for the *early return zealots*!  They will come for you!

Comment: @trojanfoe: I guess I fall in the other camp. Do you happen to have a reference explaining why having early `return`s is a bad thing?

Comment: @John: Don't get me wrong - I'm not in their camp, and often use an early return.  I just know from experience here that some newbie coder will downvote answers for the most minor of infractions.

Comment: @John IMHO early return is fine and often useful, just don't tell any Scala programmers I said that

Comment: Early return can be abused, so some zealots say it should never be used. Some coding standards prohibit it. This is an example of a case where early return is perfectly suitable.

Comment: Thanks guys.  Just looking to fill in blind spots in my knowledge. :)